# What is the purpose of capacitors in 6.302.0x propeller circuit

Tags: arduino, switches, pwm, control-system

In this [course](https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:MITx+6.302.0x+2T2016/home) on edx it introduced the assembling of this circuit for the labs

However, I can't totally understand the purpose of some components in the circuit (shown below)

1. What is the purpose of capacitor C1?
2. I know that C2, and C3 form a low pass filter but I don't know why they are needed here.

[image: propeller driver circuit]

[image]

Comment: 1. Low pass filter. 2. Probably to get rid of unwanted fast glitches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C1 is the 1st of 3 LPF perhaps to reduce EMI and is common to both signals that follow;

PWM out has a breakpoint in its LPF to reduce PWM ripple

If Vmotor has the same breakpoint,and attenuation, the difference later provides current feedback as the series R is expected to have a low power drop.